# Session and cookies from cross site

Tags: security, session, cookies, cross-domain

I have a front end HTML website that posts requests to a WebApp hosting online. These html pages run locally on any machine. Thus, they are making cross site requests.

I am thinking of saving cookies and validating these cookies in each request that is sent to my WebApp. Is that the best way to go?

Also, when the user goes back and forth from 1 page to another, (and it is required that he is logged in), do i send a request with cookie from the HTML at the start of the page and redirect him to login page accordingly if his cookie is not valid?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think this question might be a better fit on http://security.stackexchange.com/ since you're not asking for the coding part but the security implications, if i understand correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are planning to go about seems alright. Ofcourse you will have to think well about how you are going to save your access tokens. I would use an access token with the IP, username and session expiration date encoded in it.

However just checking on page load would not be the best idea since the result of the check could be spoofed. You should sent this acces token with every request for information so your webapp can decide wether or not to reply with information.

Comment: Aha great. By IP/username/sessionexp encoding, u mean the cookie value that i create, should be the encryption of these 3 values?

Comment: Yes, with that you can check serverside whether the user still has rights to acces the page. The ip to make sure that the user can only request data from the ip he has logged in from (counters man-in-the-middle attacks that 'steal' the access token to gain acces to the page, unless the attacker is on the same network), the username for your own handling of which data should be sent and the session expiration for an extra security measure. (gives attackers less time to use the stolen access tokens). Fully protected is very hard but this is a good way to start and discourage most attackers.